Python pydub issue: Can't repoen a wav file after it as been reencoded by ffpeg [Silved]
Solved by Michael Butscher. Updated code is now in the repo in the fixed branch. Thanks!
I have a python script that reads in all the *.wav files in a directory and saves them in a folder called output after it adjusts their volume.
lower.py:
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment as ass

# get the current working directory
current_working_directory = os.getcwd()
all_files = os.listdir();

 


while len(all_files) > 0:
    file = all_files.pop()
    song = ass.from_wav(file)
    song = song - 16
    song.export('out\\'+file)


https://github.com/tibberous/ChangeWavVolume/tree/fixed
The problem is (and this took me a LONG time to figure out), after the files are output once, if you try to read them again with AudioSegment ::from_wav(file), ffmpeg throws an error saying it can't decode the file. The output wav files play in Windows Media Player, and even have their audio adjusted, but I am guessing there somehow an error either in the file data itself or the file headers.
I put the code on github. Checkout the branch 'fixed'.
Btw, I just installed everything, so I should have the current versions of everything. I am using the Chocolatey package manager for Windows 10. Read README.txt (in progress) to see how I setup my dev environment.


Python 3.12.2
Chocolatey v2.2.2
C:\Users\moren>C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 7.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
Universal media converter



I opened the wav files the program generated with Media Player, VLC Media Player and Audacity, thinking they might throw an error, but the only thing that can't seem to read the exported wav files is the script that created them!

I should have created a code block initially, and tried to go back to edit one in, but couldn't figure out how to do it, so I used a JavaScript snippet instead.

Try to explicitly specify the format: song.export('out\\'+file, format='wav')

This was the issue. It seems like this might be a bug in the library though? Like, if leaving it blank is possible, and should it detect it is a *.wav and set the filetype to wav?

Maybe a missing feature. The documentation doesn't say that the type is auto-detected.
